# jQuery Mobile Function not returning (OO)

Tags: jquery, oop, jquery-mobile

I am trying a bit Object Oriented jQuery but I am not getting far.
I created two methods;

- `DoConnect` -> AJAX request to check if a URL is available.
  `callback(true)` if connection succeed, `callback(false)` if it
  failed.
- `Connect` -> Called from whereever it needs to be called.

**What works?**

`DoConnect` tries to connect to the host and sends a `callback`. This works just fine.
`Connect` reads this `callback`, also working fine. (I tested this by adding `alert` to return the `callback`'s boolean value)

**What doesn't?**

Well, `Connect` reads the `callback` and has to `return` a value to where it is called in the first place.

**The code I have so far**

*The class and the `Connect` method*

```
var Class = 
{
    Connect : function(host, apikey)
    {
        var returnVal;

        DoConnect(host, apikey, function(res)
        {
            if (res)
            {
                // alert('TRUE');
                returnVal = true;
            }
            else
            {
                // alert('FALSE');
                returnVal = false;
            }
        });

        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

*The `DoConnect` method*

```
var DoConnect = function(host, apikey, callback)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: host + "/api?do=ping&" + apikey,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(e)
        {
            if (e.status != undefined)
            {
                callback(false);
            }
            else
            {
                callback(true);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

*I call it like this;*

```
var IsConnected = Class.Connect(host, apikey);
alert(IsConnected) // Returns undefined.
```

Chrome's debugging console returns no errors.
What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `returnVal` returns before an answer can be there. The return value is asynchronous, you have to stay asynchronous the whole chain.

You need to add a callback to the `Connect`function too, like:

```
Connect : function(host, apikey, callback)
```

then you call the callback inside of the callback of the DoConnect function:

```
        if (res)
        {
            // alert('TRUE');
            return callback(true);
        }
        else
        {
            // alert('FALSE');
            return callback(false);
        }
```

You can call your function then like:

```
Class.Connect(host, apikey, function(returnValue) {
    alert(returnValue);
});
```

Comment: Perfect. I was thinking about the entire call being async could form the problem but I had no idea the fix was this easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait for the ajax call to finish before returning a value.  This can be accomplished by setting the `async` option to false like … oh wait, no it can't.

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not support synchronous operation.

Ok, so we have to do a good old fashioned poll loop:

```
... // after $.ajax call
while(typeof(returnVal) === "undefined");

return returnVal;
```

It specifically defeats the asynchronous nature of the jquery call (the first "A" in "AJAX"), but if that's the functionality you need, this will get you there.